# How do I convert an ActiveRecord result array to a normal array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I convert the resultset of @recipe.components.find ( [# <Component ingredient_id: 1>, # <Component> ingredient_id: 2>] ) to an array such as [1,2]

```
<% @ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= check_box_tag 'ingredients[]', ingredient.id, @recipe.components.find(:all, :select => "ingredient_id").include?(ingredient.id) %><%= ingredient.name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you can use

```
@result.map {|i| i.ingredient_id }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I needed @result.map! { |i| i.ingredient_id }

Comment: `map` is your friend. Also get to know the "ect" triplets: `select`, `reject` and `inject`.

Answer (score 25):

If you are using a recent version of ruby, there is new way to do this:

```
@result.map(&:ingredient_id)
```

Time saver, clean and easy to interpret.

Comment: Looks like Ruby is gaining even more ability to be cryptic then.

Comment: @Spechal it's not to be cryptic! Simply put, the map method exposes the underlying enumeration interface for any array, hash, etc. The "&" is just short notation when you wish to send / trigger a single method on each object in the array. And in this case the :ingredient_id is the symbol representation of the method.

Comment: @Spechal Oh and I forgot to mention, if you are using Rails 3.2.x there is a simpler method! Just call MyModel.find(*conditions*).pluck(&:ingredient_id)... this is much faster since the pluck method is basically a single column select so you wont waste time in fetching all the data, presuming of course that you only want the values in a single column!

Answer (score 6):

Or more succinctly `@result.map! &:ingredient_id`

Answer (score 6):

You could also use:

```
@result.pluck(:ingredient_id)
```