# How to return a result composed of two changed has_and_belongs_to_many relations

Tags: ruby, activerecord

`r` is an array that has three items that is the result of

```
r = Part.components.products.uniq
```

where Part HABTM Component and Component HABTM Product.

Why does this code:

```
class Array
  def p_object_ids
    puts each { object_id }.join(", ")
  end
end

p r.class
r.p_object_ids
p r.count
```

generate this output:

```
Array
#&lt;User:0x00000006535650&gt;, #&lt;User:0x000000065338f0&gt;, #&lt;User:0x000000065336e8&gt;
1
```

Comment: Is it an array containing an array? What does `p r` show?

Comment: Well this is embarassing: "p r returns &lt;#ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy &lt;..."  So I guess I need a way to convert that CollectionProxy to an array.  This is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241211/how-do-i-convert-an-activerecord-result-array-to-a-normal-array).

Comment: Also, you should be using `Array#length` when you don't need the special features of `count`.

Comment: and which `r.size`, and `r.each {|o|p o.class}` will output

Comment: I suggest you add a Rails tag if part of the problem will be converting `CollectionProxy` to an array.

Comment: r is actually the result of several nested has_many relations.  For example, lets say part has_and_belongs_to_many components, and component HABTM products.  I want to know which products any given part is being used to build.  So I'm writing something the equivalent of "def Part.products ... end".  I started out wanting this to return an array, but now I want it to return a Relation that can be chained like any other.

Comment: I got it to work by doing the equivalent to "return Product.where("id in (select component_id from components_products cd where (cd.part_id in (select id from components_parts ct where ct.part_id = #{the_part_id}".  That's not very elegant.  I would rather use CollectionProxy#build to compose this out of Part#components and Component#products, but don't have the Ruby chops yet.  I think I'll start a new question.

Comment: Good idea to start over.  This is pretty ugly.  :-)

Comment: This might be a little less ugly: 
def Part.products Prooduct.joins(components: :part).where(parts: {id: self.id}) end

Answer (score 1):

It returns 1 when it's not really an array of three items, but an Array containing a single ActiveRecord.  The correct implementation of what I was looking for turned out to be:

```
class Part
    def products
        Prooduct.joins(components: :part).where(parts: {id: self.id}) 
    end
end
```

and not

```
self.components.map(&:products).uniq.to_a
```